# Find rows in database where multiple values equal column value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller which focuses on a user, which can have many customers (through using a pivot table). At the moment (which doesn't work) this is my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $customer = Auth::user()->customers;
        $customerID = $customer->id;
            $shipFromShipments = shipment::where('ship_from', '=', $customerID)->get();
            $shipFromShipmentsCount = $shipFromShipments->count();

            $shipToShipments = shipment::where('ship_to','=', $customerID)->get();
            $shipToShipmentsCount = $shipToShipments->count();

            $billToShipments = shipment::where('bill_to', '=', $customerID)->get();
            $billToShipmentsCount = $billToShipments->count();

        $customersCount = $customer->count();
        return view('home', compact('customer','shipFromShipmentsCount','shipToShipmentsCount','billToShipmentsCount','customersCount'));
    }
```

At the moment, I get this error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Related to the line `$customerID = $customer->id`, obviously because it can return multiple instances.

What I'd like is if a user has multiple customers (say 1, 3, and 4), then the `$shipFromShipments` row search will look in the column "ship_from" where a 1, 3, or 4 is present and then get a count of all the rows where any of those numbers are present.

I've done this with single values, but not multiple.

--Update dd($customer)

```
Collection {#310 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => customer {#309 ▼
      #fillable: array:19 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:34 [▶]
      #original: array:36 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #excludedAttributes: []
      #auditEvent: null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend getting a working raw MySQL query first.

Comment: dd($customer) after $customer = Auth::user()->customers and check

Comment: @Sohel0415 - I have included the results you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to fetch single **id** from a **collection** of array.

```
$customerID = $customer->id;
```

At the above line, it is expected it is a single collection but having array of collection. That's why it is getting Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance error.

Make sure you get a single instance of customer object. May be something like the following...

```
$customer = Auth::user()->customer;
```

Or use **foreach** function to have the **customer_id**